# How to dump a binary file as a C/C++ string literal?

Tags: c, hexdump, xxd

I have a binary file I would like to include in my C source code (temporarily, for testing purposes) so I would like to obtain the file contents as a C string, something like this:

```
\x01\x02\x03\x04
```

Is this possible, perhaps by using the `od` or `hexdump` utilities?  While not necessary, if the string can wrap to the next line every 16 input bytes, and include double-quotes at the start and end of each line, that would be even nicer!

I am aware that the string will have embedded nulls (`\x00`) so I will need to specify the length of the string in the code, to prevent these bytes from terminating the string early.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13856930/560648

Comment: I want similar but retain ascii printable glyph, only escaping 1-127, quote, backslash, null, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can *almost* do what you want with `hexdump`, but I can't figure out how to get quotes & single backslashes into the format string. So I do a little post-processing with `sed`. As a bonus, I've also indented each line by 4 spaces. :)

```
hexdump -e '16/1 "_x%02X" "\n"' filename | sed 's/_/\\/g; s/.*/    "&"/'
```

**Edit**

As Cengiz Can pointed out, the above command line doesn't cope well with short data lines. So here's a new improved version:

```
hexdump -e '16/1 "_x%02X" "\n"' filename | sed 's/_/\\/g; s/\\x  //g; s/.*/    "&"/'
```

---

As Malvineous mentions in the comments, we also need to pass the `-v` verbose option to `hexdump` to prevent it from abbreviating long runs of identical bytes to `*`.

```
hexdump -v -e '16/1 "_x%02X" "\n"' filename | sed 's/_/\\/g; s/\\x  //g; s/.*/    "&"/'
```

Comment: This produces redundant and invalid elements if input is shorter than 16 bytes.

Comment: @CengizCan: :oops:! Is that better?

Comment: Need to add the `-v` option to `hexdump`, otherwise long runs of the same input byte cause output lines that say `"*"`.

Comment: @Malvineous Good point! I've amended my answer. Thanks for the heads-up (and thanks for accepting my answer).

Answer (score 82):

[`xxd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) has a mode for this. The `-i`/`--include` option will:

> output in C include file style. A complete static array definition is written (named after the input file), unless xxd reads from stdin.

You can dump that into a file to be `#include`d, and then just access `foo` like any other character array (or link it in). It also includes a declaration of the length of the array.

The output is wrapped to 80 bytes and looks essentially like what you might write by hand:

```
$ xxd --include foo
unsigned char foo[] = {
  0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64,
  0x21, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x59, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x27, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x76, 0x65,
  0x72, 0x79, 0x20, 0x63, 0x75, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x73, 0x21, 0x20,
  0x57, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x0a
};
unsigned int foo_len = 47;
```

`xxd` is, somewhat oddly, part of the `vim` distribution, so you likely have it already. If not, that's where you get it — you can also build the tool on its own out of the `vim` source.

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know I had xxd. Now I just have to remember it exists next time I need it... or I'll probably just replicate the required functionality in Python. :)

Comment: `objcopy` would be better

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `objcopy` would allow OP to link the binary data with the executable as an object file, which is useful but not exactly what's being asked here.

Comment: @WanderNauta: You would access it in pretty much the same way as you'd access `foo`/`foo_len` here, _and_ you wouldn't be vastly wasting storage space. I am convinced that the OP would be better off with `objcopy` and that it suits his or her requirements.

Comment: `objcopy` is fine when it's around, but it's not portable and the output even less so. It can certainly be part of a good permanent solution, but that isn't the question here.

Comment: `xxd` is the best!

Answer (score 5):

`xxd` is good but the result is highly verbose and takes a lot of storage space.

You can achieve practically the same thing using [`objcopy`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?objcopy+1); e.g.

```
objcopy --input binary \
    --output elf32-i386 \
    --binary-architecture i386 foo foo.o
```

Then link `foo.o` to your program and simply use the following symbols:

```
00000550 D _binary_foo_end
00000550 A _binary_foo_size 
00000000 D _binary_foo_start
```

This is not a string literal, but it's essentially the same thing as what a string literal turns into during compilation (consider that string *literals* do not in fact exist at run-time; indeed, none of the other answers actually give you a string literal even at compile-time) and can be accessed in largely the same way:

```
unsigned char* ptr = _binary_foo_start;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < _binary_foo_size; i++, ptr++)
   putc(*ptr);
```

The downside is that you need to specify your target architecture to make the object file compatible, and this may not be trivial in your build system.

Answer (score 4):

Should be exactly what you asked for:

```
hexdump -v -e '"\\" "x" 1/1 "%02X"' file.bin ; echo
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, imo.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short utility I wrote that essentially does the same thing (originally posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679968/147126)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 80

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fout = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    if(ferror(fout))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening output file");
        return 1;
    }
    char init_line[]  = {"char hex_array[] = { "};
    const int offset_length = strlen(init_line);

    char offset_spc[offset_length];

    unsigned char buff[1024];
    char curr_out[64];

    int count, i;
    int line_length = 0;

    memset((void*)offset_spc, (char)32, sizeof(char) * offset_length - 1);
    offset_spc[offset_length - 1] = '\0';

    fprintf(fout, "%s", init_line);

    while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        count = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff) / sizeof(char), stdin);

        for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            line_length += sprintf(curr_out, "%#x, ", buff[i]);

            fprintf(fout, "%s", curr_out);
            if(line_length >= MAX_LENGTH - offset_length)
            {
                fprintf(fout, "\n%s", offset_spc);
                line_length = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fseek(fout, -2, SEEK_CUR);
    fprintf(fout, " };");

    fclose(fout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you also provided the input and output examples with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into python, load it into a variable "buff" and use something like this:

```
buff2 = buff.encode("hex")
print ("0x"+", 0x".join([buff2[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(buff2),2)]))
```