# Embedding a binary and exec it, feasibility

Tags: process, exec

I have a binary daemon that depends on another binary daemon at runtime to exist; I don't like this arrangement. (My code works on both OS X and Linux I say linux because I believe its okay to only assume `elf` file formatting)

I knew about `xxd` but thankfully found this post as well: [How to dump a binary file as a C/C++ string literal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/how-to-dump-a-binary-file-as-a-c-c-string-literal) which uses `objdump`.

I was thinking that it ought to be possible to create arch specific obj files then at runtime do a match like so:

In pseudo OCaml

```
match arch with 
| Linux_32_bit -> 
  write_to_file "/tmp/foo" "linux_bin_32"; 
  Child_process.popen "/tmp/foo"
| Darwin_64_bit ->
  ...
```

I was thinking that this on the face of it ought to work, assuming that the libraries that the embedded binary exist in the proper locations, other implementation details.

Is this even possible or a waste of time?

Comment: Can't you have an install phase that'll have made sure that you always have the dependent executable where you want it?

Comment: No, the goal is to create a more self contained program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine.

Here's a C example that embeds `cat`, and upon execution, writes it to a tempfile, and marks it executable:

```
//$ xxd --include /bin/cat
//^ create _bin_cat and _bin_cat_len
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(){
  //TODO: error checking everywhere
  char tmp[] = "/tmp/cat-XXXXXX"; 
  mkstemp(tmp);
  FILE* f = fopen(tmp, "w");
  fwrite(_bin_cat, _bin_cat_len, 1, f);
  fchmod(fileno(f), 0700);
  puts(tmp); //print the name of where the embeded cat got copied to
  return 0;
}
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Brilliant, works on OSX.